# Convert TemplateField to DateTime - Blank Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, gridview, templatefield

All of the dates are becoming empty even if there are dates present in the cell. This is from a gridview template field. I am trying to convert those cells that are not empty but instead, all of them are empty.

```
 asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("assigned_date") != null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("assigned_date")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")  %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It better to create a function on code behind and call that function - avoid the inline `Eval`. So the code will be as:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# getDateTimeIfExist(Container.DataItem)%>'></asp:Label>
```

and on code behind

```
protected string getDateTimeIfExist(object oItem)
{
        var DateTimeToRender = DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "assigned_date") as DateTime?;

        if (DateTimeToRender != null)
            return DateTimeToRender.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        else
            return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: it's still blank

Comment: debug it step by step to see why - its maybe not null, but `DBNull` - or else you have type something wrong  - possible the "assigned_date" - check what is return there, make some tests

Comment: I resolved it already and added the answer here. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by checking for DBNull instead of null

The ? means then
The : mean else

```
Text='<%# Eval("assigned_date") != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("assigned_date")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : ""
```